# How to run javascript function in "background" / without freezing UI

Tags: javascript

I've done an HTML form which has a lot of questions (coming from a database) in many different tabs. User then gives answers in those questions. Each time a user changes a tab my Javascript creates a save. The problem is that I have to loop through all questions each time the tab is changed and it freezes the form for about 5 seconds every time.

I've been searching for an answer how I can run my save function in the background. Apparently there is no real way to run something in the background and many recommend using `setTimeout();` For example this one [How to get a group of js function running in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204877/how-to-get-a-group-of-js-function-running-in-background)

But none of these examples does explain or take into consideration that even if I use something like `setTimeout(saveFunction, 2000);` it doesn't solve my problem. It only postpones it by 2 seconds in this case.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: This looks like you don't use asynchronous io? How have you written the loop and save code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Apparently there is no real way to run something on background...

There is on [most modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers) (but not IE9 and earlier): [Web Workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/).

But I think you're trying to solve the problem at the wrong level: 1. It should be possible to loop through all of your controls in a **lot** less than five seconds, and 2. It shouldn't be *necessary* to loop through all controls when only one of them has changed.

I suggest looking to those problems before trying to offload that processing to the background.

For instance, you could have an object that contains the current value of each item, and then have the UI for each item update that object when the value changes. Then you'd have all the values in that object, without having to loop through all the controls again.

Comment: Totally agree. Even if you were able to run this in the background, you then have an issue where the user *thinks* the application is responsive but actually it's still in the middle of calculating things. The more efficient solution is to work out why your code takes 5 seconds

Comment: I knew someone would point it out that my code might be little heavy, which propably is true I admit. But let's put that aside. I could have all the questions on one page and in worst case they all should be looped through then. When it comes to Web Workers (which I'm going to read about later today, thank you for pointing that out) I can't use them. We're using IE8 here and this solution must be "bullet proof". If I can't find out how to solve this smoothly I might just add a loading gif to the screen.

Comment: @kivikall: *"But let's put that aside."* I wouldn't, if I were you. Five seconds is an *insanely* long period of time for a modern computer, even one running IE8. The right solution here is to identify the reasons for it taking that long, and deal with those reasons -- through caching previous answers to an object (as described), etc.

Comment: Chrome has some great debugging tools to help you [see where most CPU time is being spent](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/cpu-profiling). Ignoring the performance issues *is* an option, but a very weak one. Javascript is [pretty powerful](http://labs.gooengine.com/videosphere/) so describing some form manipulation as a "little heavy" when it's taking 5 *seconds* to complete sounds honestly like an understatement

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You're absolutely right and I'm gonna re-think it. But even if it would take only 0,1 sec using a setTimeout() would only postpone the execution right? And therefore I'm a bit confused because if it's fast enough to not catch user's attention why would I'd like to use async at all. And if it would be too slow I don't really care if it occurs before or after the tab is changed. So my original question is still on.

Comment: @kivikall: My point is that if you're just gathering information, it should be so fast you don't need background processing. `setTimeout` solutions just work by making the page more responsive by breaking the work up into small chunks and allowing the browser a chance to do things between processing the chunks. Typically these will make the total time required to do the processing longer (sometimes a lot longer), the *only* advantage is that the browser isn't locked up between chunks.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sure, that makes sense. What would be the right way to do "background processing" if not using Web Workers? I know it's possible to load some files in background by using jQuery's Ajax() function for example? What would be similar for running functions? I'm not talking about my form anymore, but more in general if I ever have to do such a thing. Or is it so that I pray on my knees that our browsers will be updated.

Comment: Aside from web workers, Javascript in browsers is single threaded. Any time you have long-running code, you're blocking interaction with the page.

Comment: @kivikall: Unfortunately, without web workers, you can't. [Which is why we have web workers. :-) ] The reason ajax runs in the background is specific to the underlying mechanism (the `XMLHttpRequest` object), it's not something jQuery does, and sadly it can't be applied to code running in the browser. Your JavaScript functions will always run on the UI thread, unless you use web workers, which sadly you can't because they're not in IE8. :-(

Answer (score 20):

You can use [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers). Some of the older answers here say that they're not widely supported (which I guess they weren't when those answers were written), but today [they're supported by all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers).

To run a web worker, you need to create an instance of the built-in `Worker` class. The constructor takes one argument which is the URI of the javascript file containing the code you want to run in the background. For example:

```
let worker = new Worker("/path/to/script.js");
```

Web workers are subject to the same origin policy so if you pass a path like this the target script must be on the same domain as the page calling it.

If you don't want to create an new Javascript file just for this, you can also use a data URI:

```
let worker = new Worker(
    `data:text/javascript,
    //Enter Javascript code here
    `
);
```

Because of the same origin policy, you can't send an AJAX request from a data URI, so if you need to send an AJAX request in the web worker, you must use a separate Javascript file.

The code that you specify (either in a separate file or in a data URI) will be run as soon as you call the `Worker` constructor.

Unfortunately, web workers don't have access to neither outside Javascript variables, functions or classes, nor the DOM, but you can get around this by using the `postMessage` method and the `onmessage` event. In the outside code, these are members of the worker object (`worker` in the example above), and inside the worker, these are members of the global context (so they can be called either by using `this` or just like that with nothing in front).

`postMessage` and `onmessage` work both ways, so when `worker.postMessage` is called in the outside code, `onmessage` is fired in the worker, and when `postMessage` is called in the worker, `worker.onmessage` is fired in the outside code.

`postMessage` takes one argument, which is the variable you want to pass (but you can pass several variables by passing an array). Unfortunately, functions and DOM elements can't be passed, and when you try to pass an object, only its attributes will be passed, not its methods.

`onmessage` takes one argument, which is a `MessageEvent` object. The `MessageEvent` object has a `data` attribute, which contains the data sent using the first argument of `postMessage`.

Here is an example using web workers. In this example, we have a function, `functionThatTakesLongTime`, which takes one argument and returns a value depending on that argument, and we want to use web workers in order to find `functionThatTakesLongTime(foo)` without freezing the UI, where `foo` is some variable in the outside code.

```
let worker = new Worker(
    `data:text/javascript,
    function functionThatTakesLongTime(someArgument){
        //There are obviously faster ways to do this, I made this function slow on purpose just for the example.
        for(let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++){
            someArgument++;
        }
        return someArgument;
    }
    onmessage = function(event){    //This will be called when worker.postMessage is called in the outside code.
        let foo = event.data;    //Get the argument that was passed from the outside code, in this case foo.
        let result = functionThatTakesLongTime(foo);    //Find the result. This will take long time but it doesn't matter since it's called in the worker.
        postMessage(result);    //Send the result to the outside code.
    };
    `
);

worker.onmessage = function(event){    //Get the result from the worker. This code will be called when postMessage is called in the worker.
    alert("The result is " + event.data);
}

worker.postMessage(foo);    //Send foo to the worker (here foo is just some variable that was defined somewhere previously).
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at [HTML5 web workers](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp), they're not all that widely supported though.

Comment: [Today all modern browsers support them.](https://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers)

Answer (score 2):

This works in background:

```
setInterval(function(){ d=new Date();console.log(d.getTime()); }, 500);
```

Comment: It doesn't really, though. The only thing that's doing "in the background" is _sleeping_; the function is actually _run_ in the "foreground", and if it were doing something more heavyweight than simply `d=new Date();console.log(d.getTime());` (for example, if it were doing a huge tree search or factoring prime numbers or something) then you'd see your UI freezing up while it ran.

Comment: this doesn't work on background in phone

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use web workers because you need to access the DOM, you can also use [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). The idea is to create an async `refreshUI` function that refreshes the UI, and then call that function regularly in your function that takes long time.

The `refreshUI` function would look like this:

```js
async function refreshUI(){
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 0));
}
```

In general, if you put `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));` in an async function, it will run all the code before that line, then wait for `ms` milliseconds without freezing the UI, then continues running the code after that line. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914235/4284627) for more information.

The `refreshUI` function above does the same thing except that it waits zero milliseconds *without freezing the UI* before continuing, which in practice means that it refreshes the UI and then continues.

If you use this function to refresh the UI often enough, the user won't notice the UI freezing.

Refreshing the UI takes time though (not enough time for you to notice if you just do it once, but enough time for you to notice if you do it at every iteration of a long for loop). So if you want the function to run as fast as possible while still not freezing the UI, you need to make sure not to refresh the UI too often. So you need to find a balance between refreshing the UI often enough for the UI not to freeze, but not so often that it makes your code significantly slower. In my use case I found that refreshing the UI every 20 milliseconds is a good balance.

You can rewrite the `refreshUI` function from above using [`performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) so that it only refreshes the UI once every 20 milliseconds (you can adjust that number in your own code if you want) no matter how often you call it:

```js
let startTime = performance.now();
async function refreshUI(){
    if(performance.now() > startTime + 20){    //You can change the 20 to how often you want to refresh the UI in milliseconds
        startTime = performance.now();
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 0));
    }
}
```

If you do this, you don't need to worry about calling `refreshUI` to often (but you still need to make sure to call it often enough).

Since `refreshUI` is an async function, you need to call it using `await refreshUI()` and the function calling it must also be an async function.

Here is an example that does the same thing as the example at the end of [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62349015/4284627), but using this method instead:

```js
let startTime = performance.now();
async function refreshUI(){
    if(performance.now() > startTime + 20){    //You can change the 20 to how often you want to refresh the UI in milliseconds
        startTime = performance.now();
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 0));
    }
}

async function functionThatTakesLongTime(someArgument){
    //There are obviously faster ways to do this, I made this function slow on purpose just for the example.
    for(let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++){
        someArgument++;
        await refreshUI();    //Refresh the UI if needed
    }
    return someArgument;
}

alert("The result is " + await functionThatTakesLongTime(3));
```

Answer (score -1):

This library helped me out a lot for a very similar problem that you describe: https://github.com/kmalakoff/background

It basically a sequential background queue based on the WorkerQueue library.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at it but I'm afraid I can't use it either. Not because it's unusable but in this current project our policy is to use only very well known extensions (which basically means only jQuery) or native components. Can't help it. But I'll take a look at that anyway and let you know if that could solve my problem.

Answer (score -6):

Just create a hidden button. pass the function to its onclick event.
Whenever you want to call that function (in background), call the button's click event.

```
<html>
<body>
    <button id="bgfoo" style="display:none;"></button>

    <script>
    function bgfoo()
    {
        var params = JSON.parse(event.target.innerHTML);
    }

    var params = {"params":"in JSON format"};
    $("#bgfoo").html(JSON.stringify(params));
    $("#bgfoo").click(bgfoo);
    $("#bgfoo").click(bgfoo);
    $("#bgfoo").click(bgfoo);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does this step outside of Javascript's usual Synchronous execution ? Or Emulate Threading ?